# Why does blockchain.info show the warning "Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: The transaction is not final"?

Tags: blockchain.info, blockexplorer, sequence

The transaction `fc3f81c625720063c5cab2145bcb5ef20b13ff0aa73b0b2435ffdb645acfcb8b` has the warning "Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: The transaction is not final." [on Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/search?search=fc3f81c625720063c5cab2145bcb5ef20b13ff0aa73b0b2435ffdb645acfcb8b).

The same transaction shows up with five confirmations [on Blockexplorer.com](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/fc3f81c625720063c5cab2145bcb5ef20b13ff0aa73b0b2435ffdb645acfcb8b).

What does that "the transaction is not final" mean, and why did blockchain.info reject the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

[BTCJerk on reddit noticed](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5h0b38/why_does_blockchaininfo_show_the_warning/dawdkae/) that "Blockchain.info is having issues, the last block they show is 442341". Other block explorers were already on block 442349…

Since the transaction was [timelocked](https://webbtc.com/tx/fc3f81c625720063c5cab2145bcb5ef20b13ff0aa73b0b2435ffdb645acfcb8b) until block 442345, and timelocked transactions are considered invalid until the appropriate blockchain height is reached, blockchain.info was still considering the transaction invalid due to its lagging behind.